# DataTables | How to do your own select?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, datatables

Hello i use the tablesorter-plugin [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). 
I use it with serverside processing and ajax pipelining.

Here is my actual serverside script:

```
                <?php
            // Datenbank-Tabelle, die verwendet wird
            $table = 'loginlogs';

            // Der Primary key, der Tabelle
            $primaryKey = 'id';

            // Das "datetime"-Format aus der Datenbank extrahieren, nur das Datum (in das Deutsche-Format)
            function getonlydate($datetime){
                $exploded = explode("-", $datetime);
                $explodemeagain = explode(" ", $exploded[2]);
                $mergeme = $explodemeagain[0].".".$exploded[1].".".$exploded[0];
                return $mergeme;
            }

            // Das "datetime"-Format aus der Datenbank extrahieren, nur die Uhrzeit
            function getonlytime($datetime){
                $exploded = explode("-", $datetime);
                $explodemeagain = explode(" ", $exploded[2]);
                $mergeme = $explodemeagain[1];
                return $mergeme;
            }

            // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
            // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
            // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple indexes.
            $columns = array(
                array( 'db' => 'ip', 'dt' => 0 ),
                array(
                    'db'        => 'status',
                    'dt'        => 1,
                    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                        if($d == 1){
                            return "Erfolgreich";
                        }else{
                            return "Fehlgeschlagen";
                        }
                    }
                ),
                array(
                    'db'        => 'stayloggedin',
                    'dt'        => 2,
                    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                        if($d == 1){
                            return "Ja";
                        }else{
                            return "Nein";
                        }
                    }
                ),
                array(
                    'db'        => 'date',
                    'dt'        => 3,
                    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                        return getonlydate($d);
                    }
                ),
                array(
                    'db'        => 'date',
                    'dt'        => 4,
                    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                        return getonlytime($d);
                    }
                )
            );

            // SQL server connection information
            require('../../phpfuncs/connection.php');
            $sql_details = array(
                'user' => $user,
                'pass' => $pw,
                'db'   => $db,
                'host' => $host
            );

            require('ssp.class.php');

            echo json_encode(
                SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table,  $primaryKey, $columns )  
            );
            ?>
```

Now my question is how can i do specific selects?
A specific select like:

```
"SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE userid=16"
```

I already searched on their website for some documentations but i can only find docs about filtering, and so on. Clientside stuff, but nothing about specific serverside possibilities.

Maybe somebody also use datatables and tablesorter and can help me out with an example?

Comment: The `SSP` class you're using is just a sample interface to show you how it's done. If you want more flexibility you'll need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another method `SSP::complex`. From the comments in the code:

> The difference between this method and the `simple` one, is that you
>   can apply additional `where` conditions to the SQL queries. These can
>   be in one of two forms:
>
> - 'Result condition' (`$whereResult`) - This is applied to the result set, but not the
>     overall paging information query - i.e. it will not effect the number 
>     of records that a user sees they can have access to. This should be
>     used when you want apply a filtering condition that the user has sent.
> - 'All condition' (`$whereAll`) - This is applied to all queries that are made and 
>     reduces the number of records that the user can access. This should be
>     used in conditions where you don't want the user to ever have access
>     to      particular records (for example, restricting by a login id).

Function accepts the following arguments:

```
SSP::complex ($request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null)
```

So in order to apply the SQL query with `WHERE` condition, you need to change your code as follows:

```
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table,  $primaryKey, $columns, null, "userid=16" )  
);
```